# Good way to redirect user to different pages

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am using firebase in my ionic 3 app and I want to redirect user to different pages based on their status.

My current code looks like this:

```
ngOnInit():void {
let that = this;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
    //Check if user is logged in on Firebase
    if (userAuth && firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        this.storage.set("userAuth", JSON.stringify(userAuth));
        firebase.database().ref('/accounts/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                that.rootPage = TabsPage;
                that.userData = snapshot.val();
                that.storage.set("userData", JSON.stringify(that.userData)).then((userData:any) => {
                    that.events.publish('user:created', userData);
                });
                // set menuOptions
                that.menuOptions.header.username = that.userData.firstName + " " + that.userData.lastName;
                that.menuOptions.header.picture = that.userData.img;
                that.menuOptions.header.email = that.userData.email;

                let userCalories = that.calculateCalorieIntake(that.userData);
                that.storage.set("userCalories", JSON.stringify(userCalories));

                // set rootPage
                let premiumExpireDate = new Date(that.userData.premiumExpireDate);
                let now = new Date();
                if (premiumExpireDate > now) {
                    that.rootPage = PremiumPage;
                }
            } else {
                that.rootPage = OnboardingPage;
            }
        });
    } else {
        //User is not logged in, redirect to LoginPage
        that.rootPage = WelcomePage;
    }
});
```

The code works ok so far, but I have a few problems here:

**Problem 1:** Sometime a user which isn't logged in gets redirected to the "OnboardingPage", can anyone explain why?

**Problem 2:** For me the code looks really dirty so far. Do you have any recommendations to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's handle this situation in a cleaner way, so solve problem 2 first

Solution for problem 2:

There are number of refactoring techniques which you can perform. Separate the `login`, check if `loggedIn`, `userInfo` etc into a service file. Let create a service file which is called `auth.provider.ts`

**auth.provider.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {
  constructor(...) {} // inject all dependencies i.e. firebase auth modules

  login(credeitials: UserLoginForm): Observable<any> {
    // login logic
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    // is loggedin logic
    return firebase.auth().currentUser !== null;
  }

  logout(): Observable {
    // logout logic
  }

}
```

Just register this service in `app.module.ts`. Now we have created our magic wand. Just inject as dependency in any page's `constructor` where you want to address authentication.

Now lets address the problem 1;

*Sometime user redirects to OnboardingPage* that means user session is not yet expired so don't need to worry. If you want to handle user redirection to pages based upon authentication. I have following approaches for specific scenarios:

**Redirect user to login page if not logged**
In your `app.omponent.ts` file inject the AuthProvider as dependency in constructor and call method isLoggedIn() which we have created in our provider or service. if it return **false** redirect user to **LoginPage** else on **OnboardingPage**.

**Authentication check while switching between pages**
Ionic provide us page life cycle hooks in which we can write our logic. I will address specific hook related to this scenario which is call `ionViewCanEnter()` override this hook call same method of isLoggedIn() or your own method in this hook; prompt or redirect based upon user's authentication state. (must inject AuthProvider as dependency in constructor of target page)

further reading on life cycle hooks: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events